# Load all layer information from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, layer, overpass-api

I'm trying to load all points of sertain layer from OpenStreetMap. But I can't find such command in overpass api. Is this even possible?
All that I can achieve is all nodes from certain bounding box:

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <query type="way">
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>
  <recurse type="way-node" into="waynodes"/>
  <query type="node" into="nodes">
    <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
  </query>
  <!-- added by auto repair -->
  <union>
    <item/>
    <recurse type="down"/>
  </union>
  <!-- end of auto repair -->
  <print/>
</osm-script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenStreetMap doesn't have a "layer" concept in contrast to other GIS data.

For loading all existing information you simply have to query for every [element](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) type, i.e. *nodes*, *ways* and *relations*. That's all. [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) (a nice web frontend for the Overpass API) already does this by default when using the wizard.

Comment: Okay.But as I remember, I can't get a sea,for example.
http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/nQR

Comment: Yes it does. The result contains a way tagged with [natural=coastline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dcoastline). Depending in your specific problem you might have to download *all* coastline data from OSM for processing your other data correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help